# Chat (bot) invitation button

Tags: button, einstein, chat, bot

I'm having a hard time trying to setup a proper chat invitation button in order to replace the original 'Chat with an expert' text with a single image I have already loaded as a static resource within a Salesforce Site.

[image]

*(The image is just as a reference)*

The Salesforce documentation is quite confusing at this point and I'm beginning to feel I just missed the spot and now I'm wandering around...

Any help would be very much appreciated
Thanks in advance.
Bernardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer to this question. It wasn't easy to find but after I understood what to do, it became pretty easy...

1. Remove the "Chat with an expert" button via editing this line in the script:

   ```
    embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = false;
   ```
2. Add in the page this script, so we can invoke the chat anywhere we want:

Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function bootstrapChat() {
        embedded_svc.bootstrapEmbeddedService();
    } </script>
```

3. Define the actual button, in two tasks:

3.1. Establish the format with  as in:

```
<style>
#mybutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: 15px;
}
</style>
```

3.2. Add the image in the page, with:

```
<div id="mybutton">
    <a onclick="bootstrapChat()"><img src="{image}"></a>
</div>
```

(Note: I used a Salesforce static resource)

I remembered I had to add domains in Setup > CORS.

If anyone needs it.

Best.